# How to configure KubernetesClient to connect to AWS EKS ckluster

Tags: kubernetes, aws-sdk, fabric8

I'm trying to use io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClient to connect to my AWS EKS cluster but I'm having no luck as follows:

```
  Cluster cluster =
      EKSClient.describeCluster(DescribeClusterRequest.builder().name(clusterName).build())
          .cluster();

  final io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config kubeConfig =
      new ConfigBuilder()
          .withMasterUrl(cluster.endpoint())
          .withTrustCerts(true)
          .withRequestTimeout(10_000)
          .build();

  kubernetesClient = new DefaultKubernetesClient(kubeConfig);
```

The connection just times out so I'm sure I'm missing something. I can reach the AWS cluster with all the AWS SDK tools but those don't provide everything I need.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this question when also was looking for ways to connect to EKS. Will post my solution in case someone finds it useful.
In my case I first obtain the token with encoded IAM role via **aws eks get-token --cluster-name=my-cluster** command and then use it in the ConfigBuilder:

```
new DefaultKubernetesClient(
           new ConfigBuilder().withMasterUrl(clusterEndPoint)
                      .withOauthToken(retrievedToken).withTrustCerts(true).build());
```